# Make a python file run on the new "windows terminal" by default (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, terminal, windows-terminal

I would like to make my python file open on the "**Windows Terminal**" program instead of the python application that is opened by default. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I have created a pypi package for this https://github.com/cvzi/AssertWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OS`

```
import os

os.system("start cmd.exe /k python yourfile.py")
```

Comment: This doesn't run via Windows Terminal, and thus doesn't answer the question. Plus it uses a bunch of cmd.exe processes for no good reason and leaves an I/O mess in the original console session if the first python.exe is attached to a console.

Comment: `os.system` runs via `cmd.exe /c`. You use that for `start /B`, which reuses the current console. This runs `start` again, which runs implicitly via `cmd.exe /k start`. You're starting `cmd.exe` with an ignored `@cmd` parameter and `/k` to run python.exe. There's no `/B` for the second `start` command, so a new console is created for cmd.exe, and it runs python.exe attached to that console. Meanwhile the implied `cmd.exe /k` for the second `start` is still running and attached to the original console, chaotically competing for input with the original python.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

use the windows start command ie:

c:>start python